# There are NULL values in the Date column, and in the power bi visual my requirement is Date column should not be blank

Tags: powerbi

There are NULL values in the Date column, and in the power bi visual my requirement is Date column should not be blank. When I filter out the column "is not blank" still I am getting empty data in the column.

Comment: Add sample data. Show what you really do. Do you use some measure? How you filtered this out?

Comment: Are you sure they're null and not just blank/empty strings?